# cx_Freeze exe opens from double click but not from python os.startfile()

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a program that I created and converted to `.exe` using `cx_Freeze`.
What I'm trying to do is to open the exe file using python, I do it this way:

```
import os
os.startfile('path_to_the_file')
```

The problem is that I get a `"FileNotFoundError"` in a cx_Freeze error box.
The exe file is working when I open it from cmd or double-click it.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

This is the error I get:
[cx_Freeze error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPbmH.png)

Comment: Please share relevant part of your program `Hazam\Hazam.py`, at least line 13 which apparently causes the error. See also the FAQ [Using data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the cx_Freeze documentation.

Comment: This is Line 13: icon = pygame.image.load('Includes\Logo.png')

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to the directory of the executable before starting it:

```py
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname('path_to_the_file'))  # change to the directory of 'path_to_the_file' 
os.startfile('path_to_the_file')
```

If it is true that the executable works when you open it from `cmd` or double-click on it, this should work as well.

If you need to change back to the original working directory after starting the executable, you can try the following:

```py
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()  # get the current working directory
os.chdir(os.path.dirname('path_to_the_file'))  # change to the directory of 'path_to_the_file' 
os.startfile('path_to_the_file')
os.chdir(cwd)  # change back to the original working directory
```